# Not sure how to implement calculation for the list

Tags: swift, arraylist, foreach

Write the sum function which returns the sum of numbers in a list, using list's forEach higher order function.

//My code so far:

```
   func sum(list: [Float]) -> Float {
      ...
      list.forEach({ (n: Float) -> () in
                       ...                
       })
      return ...
}
```

Trying to figure out how to implement the caculation in my code to obtain the sum of numbers in the list.

Comment: You should read the Control Flow chapter in the Swift book. Specifically the [For-in loops](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/ControlFlow.html#ID121) section. It gives a good example that you can easily fit with `forEach`.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to get the sum using `for each` try the following.

```
func sum(list: [Float]) -> Float {
    var sum : Float = 0.0
    list.forEach({ sum += $0})
    return sum
}
```

```
let myList : [Float] = [1.0, 2.0, 1.2]
let sumOfList = sum(list : myList)
print(sumOfList) // -> 4.2
```